# move files/directpries with similar names, matching rule

Tags: shell, merge, filenames

We were moving about 4TB of files to a Windows Server08R2 from a Mac Sever. A lot of the filenames wouldn't go because of incompatible characters. We ran a renaming tool to fix the problem and copied again.
My problem is now I have a lot of folders that have very similar names like "O'Neil" and "O_Neil". In fact as far as I can tell they all conform to this rule.
There are too many to do by hand, I'm thinking of writing a script but I have limited experience with scripting. I'd like to compare the modify date or the filesize and merge or move the folders to an archive and leave one set in place. I'm not sure about best practice in this situation.

1) In theory what is the best practice, merge by date, archive the smaller versions?
2) In practice how can I go about fixing this are there tools? Script ideas?

Any help is hugely appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
find /path -type f -print0 | xargs -0 md5sum |
awk '
{
  if ($1 in seen)
    printf "duplicate: %s and %s\n", $2, seen[$1]
  else
    seen[$1] = $2
}
'
```

[Removing files with duplicate content from single directory [Perl, or algorithm]](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1747074/#1747287)